# Table CSS applying to Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Below is my css for the whole application in my master css file.

```
table {
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
overflow:visible;}

td{
height:40px;
}
```

The td height is applying to datepicker. As I am new user here, it is not allowing me to post images. This is how my image looks. Please accept the link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoPLq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS3 you can exclude the datepicker (not supported in IE8 and below)

```
td:not(.ui-datepicker td) {
    height:40px;
}
```

or give the other tables a class

```
.mytable {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow:visible;
}

.mytable td {
    height:40px;
}
```